# 403 Error on bundling CSS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have the following error on my single page app:

http://screencast.com/t/sEYhyowXTqxR

**Therefore the page looks ugly.**

My bundleconfig.cs I havent modified it:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
            AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(bundles.IgnoreList);

            bundles.Add(
                new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/modernizr")
                    .Include("~/scripts/modernizr-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(
              new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
                .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js")
                .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
              );

            bundles.Add(
             new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
                .Include("~/Content/ie10mobile.css") // Must be first. IE10 mobile viewport fix
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css")
                .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")
                .Include("~/Content/styles.css")
             );
        }
```

and my VS: (everything looks fine to me)

http://screencast.com/t/TQFAPCEsV

Update:

This happened when I changed debug mode to false on web.config, when debug mode is true the webpage renders fine  and no error is shown on the network tab

Comment: have you register bundles in global.asax file???

Comment: yes, it says:          BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

Bundling and Minification happens only when `debug=false`

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Make sure you've registered bundles in `Global.asax.`

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }
```

Make sure you have all required dll references.

```
System.Web.Optimization.dll

WebGrease.dll

Antlr3.Runtime.dll
```

And all css files should in specified valid folder.

**UPDATE**

Make sure that the virtual path for the bundle (the parameter of the StyleBundle constructor) doesn't match a folder in the filesystem

Comment: I have all 3 dlls, and in the global.asax I have this:          BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

Comment: Make sure that the virtual path for the bundle (the parameter of the StyleBundle constructor) doesn't match a folder in the filesystem.

Comment: that was the problem thank you, the font awesome nuget package creates a folder under content called css.